# Number of threads running?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

So, i have this code :

```
sem_t semt;
void* function(void* arg){
//     sem_init(&sem,0,10);
       sem_wait(&sem);
-----here
       sem_post(&sem);}
```

and i want to know how many threds are running at one moment "----here" (i know max is 10)

Comment: With just the code posted, there's no way anyone can answer your question.  You don't provide enough information.

Comment: You need to keep track of the threads' creations. There is no portable way to count the number of threads belonging to a specific process.

Comment: Count it yourself.